# SQL query is not executing on other pc after building my project

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I am trying to make a project in pyqt.after building the project in pyinstaller it works fine on my computer, but when I am trying to run the exe on different computer the qsql query is not working, although the sqlite3.connection queries are working fine.

My code looks like this:

```
 model = QSqlTableModel()
 test = QSqlDatabase("QSQLITE")
 test.setDatabaseName("shibsankar.db")
 test.open()
 qry = QtSql.QSqlQuery(test)
 qry.prepare(QString(
    "select * from Invoice_detil_summery WHERE Client_name=:value1 AND Invoice_No=:name AND (DATE(Date) BETWEEN :name2 AND :name3 )"))
 qry.bindValue(":value1", str(combo_client_name))
 qry.bindValue(":name", str(invoice_no))
 qry.bindValue(":name2", str(start_date1))
 qry.bindValue(":name3", str(end_date1))
 qry.exec_()
 model.setQuery(qry)
 self.tableView_2.setModel(model)
```

This is not working but the following query works fine on any pc.

```
 com1=sqlite3.connection()
 com1.execute("INSERT INTO Expenditure VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
                               (str(a), str(d),str(b), str(c)))
 com1.commit()
```

and in main function I have created instance like this

```
appxy=QtCore.QCoreApplication([])
```

now in project dist folder I have *

```
\qt4_plugins\sqldrivers\
```

and inside this my four files are there named

```
qsqlite4.dll, qsqlmysql4.dll, qsqlodbc.dll, qsqlpsql.dll.
```

Please tell me how to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you have any error message from the SQLite Driver ? Also, can you check, using the .drivers() function, the list of available drivers ?

Comment: @Florent Uguet thanx for ur reply. What i did is i copied all content from c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pyqt4\plugins\ and pasted it on \qt4_plugins\. and now i tasted on three different pc. it is running on all of them.. Thanx once again.